# Printing a square matrix using conditions and operators in python

Tags: python, function, operators

I am writing a function to match elements of a tuple (G) using if, elif conditions. The tuple G is a 10 by 3 tuple. G[0] is information of student 'S1' with supervisor 'SP1' and panel 'P1' which consists of three members.

The data structure is as follows:

```
[('S1', 'A8', ('A1', 'A2', 'A3')), ('S2', 'A5', ('A1', 'A2', 'A3')), ('S3', 'A6', ('A3', 'A4', 'A5')), ('S4', 'A1', ('A6', 'A7', 'A8')), ('S5', 'A4', ('A6', 'A7', 'A8')), ('S6', 'A2', ('A9', 'A10', 'A11')), ('S7', 'A3', ('A8', 'A9', 'A10')), ('S8', 'A4', ('A12', 'A13', 'A10')), ('S9', 'A10', ('A12', 'A13', 'A14')), ('S10', 'A11', ('A12', 'A13', 'A7'))]
```

The definition of the match matrix is:

- “0” means there is no conflict between the student panels. This means students can
  be allocated into the same timeslot on the same day but must be in different rooms.
  So, for example, S1, S8, S9 and S1 have no conflict with each other.
- “1” indicates there is a conflict between the student panels. This is because they
  have at least one common panel member. So these students can not be allocated into
  the same timeslot on the same day. For example, S1, S2 and S3 have common panel
  members, so they conflict with each other.
- “ 1* ” indicates the students’ conflict with each other in terms of both panels and
  supervisors. So these students can not be allocated into the same timeslot on the
  same day. For example, the S2 supervisor is a panel member of S3.
- “*” indicates students’ conflict with each other in term supervisor only. In this case,
  these students can be allocated into the same timeslot on the same day in different
  rooms, but plenty will be added to the timetable quality.
- The total of conflicts column shows the number of conflicts in each row. For
  example, S1 has 2 conflicts, S2 has 2 conflicts, S3 has 2 conflicts, and so on.

I am having trouble finding a way to match the elements based on the given definitions and print a matrix:

Tried code:

```
def matrix_generator(D1,D2,Match1):
    for i in range(len(D1)):
        for j in range(len(D2)):
            
            if D1[2][i] !=  D2[2][j] and (D1[1] == D2[2][j]) or (D2[1] == D1[2][j]):
                 Match1[i][j] = "*" 
            if D1[2][i] ==  D2[2][j]:
                Match1[i][j] = "1"
            elif (D1[1] == D2[2][j]) or (D2[1] == D1[2][j]) and (D1[2][i] !=  D2[2][j]):
                    Match1[i][j] = "*1" 
    return Match1
           
Match1 = [[0 for i in range(10)] for j in range(10)]

for i in range(0,9):
    for j in range(0,9):
        aa= matrix_generator(G[i],G[j], Match1)
print(aa)
```

I am getting output:

```
[['1', '*1', '*1', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], ['1', '1', '*1', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], ['*1', '*1', '1', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

The desired output is [Matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Womaf.png)

Can someone please explain how it can be done?

Comment: Use `return Match1` instead of `print(Match1)` when working with functions.

Comment: Thank @PCM for pointing out. I have updated the code.

Comment: and, or are logical operators, they work on boolean expressions.

Comment: I have edited the code with output can someone please open the question again?

Comment: Please provide your input data as readable text, not as link to an inappropriately cropped image. Further, clarify what you think is "incorrect" exactly and what you expect instead.

Answer (score 1):

why are you thinking `and` and `or` should give you exact result, see this example.

```
A[0,1]
B[1,1]
A[0] != B[0] and A[1] != B[1]
# True and False -> False
A[0] == B[0] or A[1] == B[1] 
# False or True -> True
```

Comment: Thank you for clarifying the working , but It still doesn't clarify the doubt. For instance I am comparing the G[0] and G[2]. The function checks in second condition if G[0][2][i] == G[2][2][j] and G[0][1] != G[2][2][j] and G[2][1] != G[0][2][j] shouldn't this condition TRUE in this case?

Comment: I get output as [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

Comment: @Sazee i don't see this condition in your code

Comment: @Sazee please send excatly input and output array and your code

Comment: I am mentioning the condition:  elif (D1[2][i] ==  D2[2][j]) and (D1[1] != D2[2][j]) and (D2[1] != D1[2][j]):
                Match1[1] = 1
                return Match1